# Tried to get data from ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I tried to get data from `ManyToManyField` but found not luck. Will you please help me?
Here is My `Song App` Models.

```
  class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True,max_length=100,help_text="Suggested value automatically generated from name. Must be unique.")


  class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True,max_length=100,help_text="Suggested value automatically generated from name. Must be unique.")
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    albumid = models.CharField(max_length=100)


  class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
    music = models.ForeignKey(Music)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
```

Here is my view. I want to print Artist with titles. `Titles` are working fine. but not `Artist`

```
 def movie_details(request,slug):
    movies = get_object_or_404(Movie,slug=slug)
    # calculating wikipedia directory structer for images
    #image_name = movies.image
    name = movies.title
    album_name = Album.objects.get(name__exact=name)
    album_id = album_name.id
    song_list = Song.objects.filter(album=album_id)
    #image_path = generateWikiImage(image_name)
    #
    return render_to_response('base_movies.html',locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                              )
```

I tried in template like this. `{{song_list.artist}}` and getting message like this `<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x024CBED0>`
thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ManyRelatedManager` is the object that handles the ManyToMany relation there. To get the list of objects that you're looking for, you need to use its `all()` method.

In this case, you'd use `{{song_list.artist.all}}`, which will give you a QuerySet that you can then iterate over in your template.

Comment: Thanks It worked. And it displaying result like this. '[<Artist: SP. Balasubramaniam>]'. I only want to print `SP. Balasubramaniam` Is it possible? thanks

Comment: `[<Artist: SP. Balasubramaniam>]` is a list, with one Artist object in it. To get the name properly, iterate over the things in this list and use `{{ artist.name }}` (if you're doing `{% for artist in song.artist.all %}`).

Answer (score 5):

`ManyToManyField` holds queryset, so you can't just output it in template. You should iterate over it.

Like this (`song` is some `Song` instance)

```
<ul>
{% for artist in song.artist.all %}
    <li>{{ artist.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you . Sorry I have only one choice.

Comment: Wish I could upvote each time I use the examples in these two replies. Still can't understand the code `{{song_list.artist.all}}`: `{{song_list.artist.all}}` worked like magic, but `{{song_list.artist.all() }}` or `{% song_list.artist.all() %}` threw errors.